# Why swagger doesn't see files in public/bundles/hbswaggerui?

Tags: symfony, swagger

I use OpenServer (Apache 2.4 + PHP 7.2).

Symfony 4 works correctly, routing works fine.
In /public folder I put .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

It works.

I installed swagger like here:
https://github.com/harmbandstra/swagger-ui-bundle

I also used assetUrlPath parameter in hb_swagger_ui.yaml

```
hb_swagger_ui:
  directory: "%kernel.root_dir%/../docs/"
  assetUrlPath: '/public/bundles/hbswaggerui/'
  files:
    - "swagger.json"
```

**url mysite/docs/?url=/docs/file/swagger.json shows white page**

console shows:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://mysite/docs/swagger-ui.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
?url=/docs/file/swagger.json:36 GET http://mysite/docs/swagger-ui-bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
?url=/docs/file/swagger.json:37 GET http://mysite/docs/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
?url=/docs/file/swagger.json:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
    at window.onload (?url=/docs/file/swagger.json:41)
```

If I make folder /public/doc/ and move there files from /public/bundles/hbswaggerui/ - it works.

But it should work in folder /public/bundles/hbswaggerui.

**Why doesn't?**

Should I do some additional Apache settings for rewrite /public/docs to /public/bundles/hbswaggerui ?

No info in manuals about it...

Answer (score 0):

You should not set `assetUrlPath`, remove it from your configuration.

Comment: I assetUrlPath as try to fix problem.
Without it doesnt work also